# How do I submit a form to two PHP processor pages?

Tags: php, html, forms

I don't have 2 forms. I don't have 2 submit buttons. I have 1 form and 1 submit button. I want to be able to do 2 different actions (or processes) when the form is submitted. I don't really want to put both actions into the same php processor file. The reason is because of 2 checkboxes in the form.

If one of those checkboxes is checked, I want to do 1 action/process. If the other is checked, I want to do a different action/process. If both are checked I want to do both actions/processes. The way I have it working is with 3 PHP processor files. One for process A, another for process B, and a third with both process A and process B in the same file, but this 3rd file is not very pretty or clean.

I have to change a bunch of variables to other variables for process B, plus it's a hassle having to update 3 files each time I have to update the first two...or it's a hassle having to update 2 files each time I have to update either process A or process B. Would be nice just to maintain 2 processor pages and that's it.

So how can I run one process after another with 2 different processor files with one form that has one submit button (based on 2 checkboxes)?

actually let me explain a bit deeper. it's actually 3 processes i'm doing. a default one which happens every time submit is pressed. doesn't matter if either of the 2 checkboxes are checked. the rest of the form is processed by the default php process which is in the same file as the form. the form submits to itself.

after the default process has run it checks for the checked checkboxes of the 2 specific checkboxes.  if one is checked, it does a header location redirect to another file which is another processor file. if the other checkbox is checked, it does a header location redirect to a another different file. if both are checked, it does a header location redirect to yet another different file which has duplicate code of the other two external processor files.

So here are the amount of pages i'm working with:

```
1) form page which also has process 1
2) process 2 page
3) process 3 page
4) process 4 page which is process 2 and 3 together
```

I would like to get rid of process 4 page if possible, and that is my question.

how the process looks in form page:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
    //bunch of processes
    //after all above proccesses done, do redirect to more processes or no more processes
    if ($checkboxone !== "" && $checkboxtwo !== "") {
      header("Location: externalactionone-and-externalactiontwo.php?id=$id");
    }
    else if ($checkboxone == "" && $checkboxtwo !== "") {
      header("Location: externalactiontwo.php?id=$id");
    }
    else if ($checkboxone !== "" && $checkboxtwo == "") {
      header("Location: externalactionone.php?id=$id");
    }
    else {
      header("Location: gosomewhereelse.php");
    }
  }
  else {
    //other process
  }
}
else {
  //other process
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on the answer given and the modifications i did to it, this is what it looks like, but it still doesn't work. the action and target are changed, but no submission happens. also i doubt it's doing multiple action and target changes and submitting to multiple iframes one after another (in a row).

```
<form id="editform" class="form-style clearfix" action="" target="" method="post">
<!--bunch of other fields-->
<input type='checkbox' id="dothis" name="dothis" value='yes' />
<input type='checkbox' id="dothat" name="dothat" value='yes' />
<input type="button" id="submittheform" class="btn" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<iframe name="frame_result1" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe name="frame_result2" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe name="frame_result3" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submittheform").click(function(){
    $("form#editform").attr('action', 'submit1.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>');
    $("form#editform").attr('target', 'frame_result1');
    $("form#editform").submit();

    var chk1="0",chk2="0";
    if($("#dothis").prop('checked') == true){
        chk1="1";
    }
    if($("#dothat").prop('checked') == true){
        chk2="1";
    }
    if(chk1==="1"){
        $("form#editform").attr('action', 'submit2.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>');
        $("form#editform").attr('target', 'frame_result2');
        $("form#editform").submit();
    }
    if(chk2==="1"){
        $("form#editform").attr('action', 'submit3.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>');
        $("form#editform").attr('target', 'frame_result3');
        $("form#editform").submit();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using some jquery code suppose your form is as follows

```
<form action="" id="form1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk2"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btn1").click(function(){
       var chk1="0",chk2="0";
       if($("#chk1").prop('checked') == true){
          //do something
          chk1="1";
        }
        if($("#chk2").prop('checked') == true){
          //do something
          chk2="1";
        }
        if(chk1==="1")
        {
            $("#form1").attr('action', 'page1.php');
            $("#form1").submit();
        }
        if(chk2==="1")
        {
            $("#form1").attr('action', 'page2.php');
            $("#form1").submit();
        }
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried to make this work, but i couldn't. it changes the action but doesn't submit. on top of that i am trying to do a default form submission that happens every time even if one of the other 2 submissions don't happen because the checkboxes are not checked.

Comment: so in other words, if chk1 checked do submission 1 and submission 2. if chk2 checked do submission 1 and submission 3. if chk1 and chk2 checked do submission 1 and 2 and 3. if chk1 or chk2 not checked do submission 1.

Comment: Just Need One more change in your updated code.change name in the `<input type="button" id="submittheform" class="btn" name="submit" value="Submit" />` to `<input type="button" id="submittheform" class="btn" name="submittheform" value="Submit" />`